# NGINX Mail proxy IMAP Auth Errors

Tags: nginx, proxy, email-server, imap

I need some help getting NGINX to perform IMAP authentication as a reverse proxy into Postfix Mail server on-prem. I am seeing the tracking on my POSTFIX mail server, but IMAP continues to fail. seems as though NGINX is not passing in the method,  mpid, or TLS. I'm not sure if the password is being passed through. I know that my login works because if I target the server directly, everything works as expected.

Here are my directives on nginx:
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
     server {
        listen  143;
        protocol imap;
        proxy on;
        imap_auth plain;
        auth_http_header user frank;
        starttls on;
        auth_http http://mail.example.com:9000/auth/imap;
        server_name mail.example.com;
        ssl_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem;

      }
```

here is my http server config:

```
server{
    listen 9000;
    server_name mail.example.com;

    location = /auth/imap {
            add_header Auth-Status OK;
            add_header Auth-Server 491.181.415.541;  # backend ip
            add_header Auth-Port   143;        # backend port
            add_header Auth-Method PLAIN;
            return 204;
      }
   }
```

Please help get this working. Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do, as Postfix doesn't handle IMAP auth (you need something like Dovecot for that), so IMAP authentication into Postfix doesn't make sense. Do you perhaps mean (or it's what you need but don't yet know it) SMTP authentication into Postfix, which is a thing but still needs additional apps to support it.